# Data safety form in google play console

Tags: android, forms, google-play, google-play-console

I need to fill data safety form in google play console. I have few doubts.

**Name and email**

Usually in android phones, the user logs in with a gmail id before starting to use the phone. This gmail id can be requested by the app like a permissions alert dialog. Now my doubt is, I am getting user's email id not like this but as a form submission. User types his email id. Now what should I mention in the data safety from. Should I mention as *collecting* or *not collecting*.

**Location**

Another similar doubt. I am not getting location using permissions. But the user types his zip code/pincode when adding his address. Should I mention *collecting* or *not collecting*.

Thank you in advance. If anyone needs more details, mention in comments and I will add it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I think you can state both as collecting.

According to [User Data](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311)

You must be transparent in how you handle user data `(e.g., information collected from or about a user, including device information)`
is going to be as data collection about the user.

Comment: I thank you for the reply. I have filled in the form and also uploaded new builds a few times after that.